# Get the 504 Gateway Timeout status code javascript

Tags: javascript, http, http-status-codes

I have an ajax call as follows-

```
this.send({
    url : AppConstants.variables.callURL.feed,
    data : rqStr,
    onSuccess : function(data, textStatus) {
           console.log(textStatus);
});

send : function(obj) {
    this.callbackObj = obj;
    FeedBackPanel.add(obj.url + "->" + obj.data);
    $.ajax({
        url : obj.url,
        data : obj.data,
        dataType : "jsonp",
        jsonp : "callback",
        jsonpCallback: "RequestController.callbackObj.onSuccess"
    });
}
```

It works fine>however i am trying to provide a wrong domain and in that case i get a

```
Status Code:504 Gateway Time-out
```

in the chrome network developer panel.However,Console.log doesn't give me that status.So is there any way i can catch the status code,so that i can take appropriate actions.

My code is working fine..I just need to catch the 504 Gateway Time-out message.Plz help.

Comment: By `catching the status code` I mean just obtain the 504 value.I have my own mechanism to deal with it.

Comment: You need an error callback, but as it is a cross domain request using `jsonp` you can only find out that the request had a timeout but you cannot figure out the status code due the way `jsonp` requests work.

Comment: how do i find out it had a timeout programatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the way `jsonp` requests works, you are not able to find out if a request failed and why.

What you can do is to set a `timeout` yourself for the `jsonp` request. If you don't get a valid response in that time, the error callback is called.

You need to figure out yourself what value you want to set for the `timeout`, because if e.g. the time required for sending the request, building the response and sending it back takes `500ms` and you set the timeout to `100ms`, the error callback will be called all the time, even if the request itself did not timeout.

```
$.ajax({
  url : obj.url,
  data : obj.data,
  dataType : "jsonp",
  jsonp : "callback",
  timeout:300,
  jsonpCallback: "RequestController.callbackObj.onSuccess"
}).success(function() {
  console.log('test')
}).error(function() {
  console.log("error");
});
```